# Connect to Sharepoint 2013 from Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, sharepoint-2013, csom

I want to create a Windows Phone app for SharePoint2013. Here's my problem. When I call ExecuteQueryAsync I get a Exception with the Message "The remote server returned an error: NotFound."

I already checked the URL, I can access it from the emulator browser

```
        using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://mysharepoint.mydomain.local/meetings/Testmeeting"))
        {
            Authenticator at = new Authenticator();


            at.UserName = "user";
            at.Password = "passwd";
            at.Domain = "mydomain";
            at.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
            at.CookieCachingEnabled = true;

            context.Load(context.Web);

            context.ExecuteQueryAsync(new ClientRequestSucceededEventHandler(ThreadCallback), new ClientRequestFailedEventHandler(ThreadFail));
        }
```

Comment: Is there a user with these credentials active on Sharepoint?

Comment: yes the user is definitely active.

I develop on a computer which is not in the same domain as sharepoint is...could that be a problem?

Comment: If you can access SharePoint through a browser then you are able to do it through code from the same computer. Perhaps there is something blocking you Windows Phone emulator's network access? If authentication was the problem then you would get a different error (access denied).

Comment: I can also access SharePoint trough the emulator browser so I think there should be everything fine with the network settings, right?